# How to set Weather API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, weather-api, openweathermap

I'm new to React Native; I'm working on weather app I have downloaded one code and run it. When I'm running it, it is giving the error that can't find variable config.
I have tried one API, but it's not working. "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22"

The URL of the code is https://github.com/Natalia504/react-native-weatherApp
and also the the API is used here is wground which doesn't provide API free so I use openweather. Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: The config file is where the owner of the repo had their API key and it's not part of the repo... If you look in the .gitignore file you will see it... You need to get your own API key and create your own config.js file...

Comment: what will i write in config.js file can you plzz help me in this

Comment: and my new api is correct?